# How to edit InputField while using EventHandler?

Tags: dynamic

I try to edit `InputField` while using `EventHandler`'s `MouseClicked`, but the `InputField` is not editable. I tried like this

`EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic[s]], {"MouseClicked" :> (Print[1])}]`

When i Click on `InputField` it print 1 but the `InputField` is not editable.

Comment: What is happening is that by wrapping in event handler you are saying that whenever you click within the area in which the event occurs (the mouse click) you will print. This means by assigning a mouse click as an event you are removing the ability to click in the input field.

Comment: Try this instead: `EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic[s]], {"MouseEntered" :> (Print[1])}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic[s]], {"MouseClicked" :> (Print[1])}, 
    PassEventsDown -> True]
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess my comment could be an answer. You need to be able to click in the input field but you have assigned mouse clicks to some other event -- in this case printing. So another way to get something to happen when the mouse is "in" the input field is to use `"MouseEntered"`

```
EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic[s]], {"MouseEntered" :> (Print[1])}]
```

But whether this is appropriate would depend on what your actual problem is (I"m assuming this is a toy example).

Another alternative is to right click in the field:

```
EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic[s]], {{"MouseClicked", 2} :> (Print[1])}]
```

but for a left click within the input field @kguler's solution looks like it is what you need.

Comment: I tried your idea but i want to print 1 only when mouse clicked on `Inputfield` And Don't want to print it before click.

Comment: @user4988 ok. just added a right click alternative.